# When I try to compile OpenCv with inference engine enabled, I am getting an error

Tags: c++, opencv, openvino

If I try to build OpenCV 4.0.0 with inferenca Engineen enabled, I am getting this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: opencv_dnn, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>dnn.cpp
1>C:\local\opencv-4.0.0\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp(1595): error C2259: 'cv::dnn::InfEngineBackendNet': cannot instantiate abstract class
1>C:\local\opencv-4.0.0\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp(1595): note: due to following members:
1>C:\local\opencv-4.0.0\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp(1595): note: 'InferenceEngine::StatusCode InferenceEngine::ICNNNetwork::serialize(const std::string &,const std::string &,InferenceEngine::ResponseDesc *) noexcept const': is abstract
1>C:\local\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445\deployment_tools\inference_engine\include\ie_icnn_network.hpp(190): note: see declaration of 'InferenceEngine::ICNNNetwork::serialize'
1>C:\local\opencv-4.0.0\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp(2556): error C2259: 'cv::dnn::InfEngineBackendNet': cannot instantiate abstract class
1>C:\local\opencv-4.0.0\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp(2556): note: due to following members:
1>C:\local\opencv-4.0.0\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp(2556): note: 'InferenceEngine::StatusCode InferenceEngine::ICNNNetwork::serialize(const std::string &,const std::string &,InferenceEngine::ResponseDesc *) noexcept const': is abstract
1>C:\local\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445\deployment_tools\inference_engine\include\ie_icnn_network.hpp(190): note: see declaration of 'InferenceEngine::ICNNNetwork::serialize'
1>Done building project "opencv_dnn.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Why I am getting this error?

## Edit

Cmake output is:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
AVX_512F is not supported by C++ compiler
AVX512_SKX is not supported by C++ compiler
Dispatch optimization AVX512_SKX is not available, skipped
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 1.5.3, BUILD = opencv-4.0.0-libjpeg-turbo
Looking for Mfapi.h
Looking for Mfapi.h - found
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
at: C:/local/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
at: C:/local/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Detected InferenceEngine: cmake package
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: C:/local/opencv-build/python_loader
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp

General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2019-02-09T13:06:47Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17134 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.13.0-rc3
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1916

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (7 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (13 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.16.27026.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4    /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          IE::inference_engine ade comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python3 python_bindings_generator stitching ts video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java js python2
    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.35)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.35.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.20.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.22.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.3.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
           at:                   C:/local/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
              at:                C:/local/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Inference Engine:            YES (2018040000 / 1.5.0)
                libs:            C:/local/Intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Release/inference_engine.lib / C:/local/Intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Debug/inference_engined.lib
            includes:            C:/local/Intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/inference_engine/include
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                C:/local/opencv-4.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe (ver 3.6.5)
    Libraries:                   C:/Program Files/Python36/libs/python36.lib (ver 3.6.5)
    numpy:                       C:/Users/m/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.4)
    packages path:               C:/Program Files/Python36/Lib/site-packages

  Python (for build):            C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/local/opencv
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Comment: Please specify with which version of IE you're trying to build OpenCV. What is version of IE is determined by OpenCV (see CMake summary from console)?

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev Please find cmake output in the edited section of the question.

Comment: IE version is determined as `2018040000`. That means you use old OpenCV version which doesn't support R5 release or you didn't clean a build folder.

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev I used OpenCv 4.0.0 from openCV.org and also I installed the latest version of OpenVino. In fact, I had the old version of OpenVino and I removed it and upgrade it to the latest version. How Cmake find the version of OpenVino or IE version?

Comment: By default, OpenCV sets the latest available version of IE (see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/dfef04b3255f4fc38d822fd4713265f21bac4cef/modules/dnn/src/op_inf_engine.hpp#L31-L34). OpenCV 4.0.0 release date is [Nov 18, 2018] which was earlier than OpenVINO R5 release. That means default version is 2018040000. I strongly recommend you to update OpenCV locally.

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev Thanks, What do you mean by update OpenCV, do you mean downgrading it to an older version or use a non-official version of OpenCV or use OpenCV which comes from Openvino? Please note that I want to use static version of OpenCV (not worls version). Do you know why Intel doesn't ship OpenCv in source code and instruction on how to compile it optimized for your Intel CPU/GPU?

Comment: What do you mean by "why Intel doesn't ship OpenCV in source code"? OpenCV from OpenVINO is a community version. If you able - you need to update OpenCV to the newest version (take it's source code from GitHub).

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev You are right that OpenCv which is shipped with OpenVino is community version, but it is in DLL format. So if I want to compile it with a different setting, I need to get the source code form gitgub. If OpenVino, has the OpenCV in the source code, then users can compile it with their own setting and benefit fromOpenvino and IE integration. Also, see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692675/flags-that-used-for-compiling-opencv-part-of-openvino

Comment: So there is a wiki about it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Intel%27s-Deep-Learning-Inference-Engine-backend. You need to take both OpenVINO and OpenCV of the latest versions. From your CMake's summary it seems that OpenCV is not the latest one.

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev Thanks, Can you please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing our discussion in comments,

OpenVINO R5 released in December however attached CMake summary shows that used OpenCV version is older (November). So the solution is to update OpenCV to the latest version which supports Intel's Inference Engine from OpenVINO R5.

Wiki of how to build OpenCV with IE support: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Intel%27s-Deep-Learning-Inference-Engine-backend